# Advice, writing a social security code

Tags: java, substring, reformat

Im new to java and my class we need to write a program where the user inputs there social security code in the form of XXXXXXXXX and it returns it in the form of XXXX-XX-XXX.
For example if there code was 123456789 it would be returned to them as 123-45-6789.

Here is what I have, I would like to use substrings to finish it off.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class HWSocialSecuritySh  {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    String name;
    int ssn;
    System.out.print ("Enter nine digit social security number without dashes: ");
    ssn= reader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Your formatted social security number is: ");
    System.out.println(snn.substring(,) );

   }
   }
```

This is the new code

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class HWSocialSecuritySH  {
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    String name;
    String Ssn="ssn";

    System.out.print ("Enter nine digit social security number without dashes: ");
    Ssn= reader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Your formatted social security number is: ");
    System.out.println (Snn.substring(0,3) +"-"snn.substring(4,6) + "-"snn.substring(7,9);

}
}
```

Comment: Why are you reading the social security number as an integer? You want to format it (not do computations with it), so might as well read it as a string.

Comment: Do you know about String concatenation? You can write "a" + "b" and it'll return "ab" as a string. Similar, if String a = "a", and String b = "b", the String c = a + b will make String c be "ab". The rest of this problem is trivial if you understand that, in my opinion, and the `charAt()` method of the String class.

Comment: @Kon ya i know that, so how exactly would you right it, please write it out in real code form, not just explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually a more appropriate way to do this would be to use a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) with a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) representing a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) containing the subgroups of the social security number as [capturing groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

```
final Pattern ssnFormat = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{4})$");

Matcher m = ssnFormat.matcher(ssn);  // make ssn a string!

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("%s-%s-%s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3));
} else {
    System.err.println("Enter a valid social security number!");
}
```

As noted, a social security number, while representable as an integer, is really a string of digits: it's meaningless as a number. Therefore, you should store it as a `String` and *not* as an `int`.

---

Now, in your new code, you're almost there, but still have a few issues:

- It's `String`, not `string`.
- Now that `ssn` is a string, you can't assign it to the result of `reader.nextInt()`, since that returns an `int`. Instead, you'll want to use `reader.nextLine()`.
- The ranges of the second and third `substring()` calls are slightly off. Refer to the method's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I would like to use only strings, because we havn't learned how to use a matcher yet. So could you please write it with just strings. Thanks :)

Comment: @ShadonHamedani Using `substring()` is very straightforward -- what part are you having trouble with? Just make 3 separate substring calls using appropriate indexes and concatenate the results with `"-"`s in between.

Comment: im new too all this so bare with me, how would i add the dashes to the substrings?

Comment: @ShadonHamedani After you've extracted the groups using `substring()`, you can use `group1 + '-' + group2 + '-' + group3`.

Comment: `substring1 + "-" + substring2`

Comment: so i tried what you said but its still giving me trouble, i posted the edited code above

Comment: @ShadonHamedani You're still reading `ssn` as an int, read it as a string and store it in a string (that's `String`, not `string`). You will need to change `nextInt()` to `nextLine()`. I've summarized this above.

Comment: @arshajii i changed them and posted the code above, now it says ")" is excepted before snn.substring(4,6). 
What do i do from here?