# How do I validate for leading zeros for an int?

Tags: java, validation

I'm trying to validate input so that the user is only allowed to input an int that has 9 digits. My current code takes care of leading zeros, any input that is more than 9 digits but not if it's less than 9 digits.

For example, it should not allow the user to input the int 123.

The code below validate for number input if the digit is longer than 9, but it does not take into account of the digits being less than 9.

```
public void setSSN(int sSN) {

    String temp = "";

    do {
        temp = String.format ("%09d", sSN);
        if(temp.length() != 9) {
            sSN = Methods.getInt("Enter an 9 digits");
        }
    }while(temp.length() != 9);

    temp = temp.substring(0,3) + "-" + temp.substring(3,5) + "-" +temp.substring(5,9);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);
    SSN = sSN;
}
```

If the user input in int less than 9 digits. It would fill in the rest of the slots and make it 9 digits due to String.format (I only include this so it would work for leading zeros). I'm not sure how to get around that leading zeros as well as making sure the input is exactly 9 digits.

TEST CASES:

Input: 123456789
Output: 123-45-6789

Input: 001234567
Output: 001-23-4567

//Below is what I don't want

Input: 12
Output: 000-00-0012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advice, writing a social security code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128108/advice-writing-a-social-security-code)

Comment: Can you provide few test cases. input and output @Truong Nguyen

Comment: @pie added test cases

Comment: Can't you just validate the length of the input before formatting it?

Comment: @AmitDas no since int does not store leading 0. So if the user input in 012345678, it would only store 12345678 (8 digits). This is the problem I ran into.

Comment: How many leading zeroes are actually allowed?

Comment: @AmitDas if's we're talking about technicality, the first 3 digits of SSN cannot be all zeros, the middle two must be from 01 - 99. But for this program, I don't mind put restriction on how many zeros. If the user input in 000 00 0001 it should run instead of 1

Comment: You cannot store leading zeroes in numbers. It has to be a string. So just validate if the user input string is of length 9 or not. And then format and store as String only

Answer (score 0):

So to want to make sure someone doesn't input "000000123"? Then just do a loop to parse the input as an array and check the value of each index and make sure that there is no recurring digits value entered in index 0-3 (which would cover you for the first 4 indexs)

Comment: Not exactly. I don't want someone to input less than 9 digits. So input like 123 or 12345 or 1234 is not ideal. But as long as it's 9 digits including lead zeros like 012345678, it should be good.

Comment: Oh. Right. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use .length to check how long the input string is. If string.legnth < 9 {cout << "sorry. Enter 9 numbers please"}

Or something like that.

Comment: You do not need to write another answer. There is a edit button under your previous answer. Press edit. and post your current answer there. @Shannon Green

Comment: Oh. So there is. Been a while since I've been on here. Thank you

Comment: I've tried this method before. If the input leading number is 0, this would not work since int does not store leading zeros, therefore the leading zero is lost when convert to a String.